# Is Hibernate and Spring integration necessary for a small application?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm creating a small application for myself which already uses Spring for dependency injection and now I am looking to use Hibernate for database development - simple CRUD operations.

I have read tutorials on Hibernate and I understand how to use it for my simple use case but I have seen that Spring and Hibernate can be integrated.

Is this integration necessary - what are the benefits of integrating rather than just using Hibernate as normal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The benefits are huge: using the declarative transaction management offered by Spring, you can avoid all the tedious and error-prone transaction- and error-management code you would need without integrating them.

A typical method using Hibernate without declarative transaction handling looks like this:

```
public void doSomeWork() {
    Session sess = factory.openSession();
    try {
        //set transaction timeout to 3 seconds
        sess.getTransaction().setTimeout(3);
        sess.getTransaction().begin();

        // do some work

        sess.getTransaction().commit()
    }
    catch (RuntimeException e) {
        sess.getTransaction().rollback();
        throw e; // or display error message
    }
    finally {
        sess.close();
    }
}
```

The same method using Spring declaration handling looks like this:

```
@Transactional
public void doSomeWork() {
    Session sess = factory.getCurrentSession();
    // do some work
}
```

Another advantage is that Spring can automatically find all the mapped entities using classpath scanning, which allows avoiding the use of a hibernate or JPA configuration file.

See [LocalSessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan()](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/LocalSessionFactoryBean.html#setPackagesToScan-java.lang.String...-)

Comment: Could you provide some examples of the error management code you speak of? I'm a beginner in regards to Hibernate and I've only ever used Spring for dependency injection so would you be able explain what errors could arise that you mentioned without integration?

Also you say that Spring can find the mappings but in this tutorial (http://www.mkyong.com/spring/maven-spring-hibernate-mysql-example/), there is still a Hibernate config file with mappings defined or am I misunderstanding your point - probably the latter!

Comment: @user2844485 done in the answer

Comment: Great, thanks. I didn't realise those try/catch statements were needed as I hadn't seen them on other tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

When you write a small application, spring boot is a good solution, with little configuration, you can scaffold your web project well. And I prefer to use jdbcTemplate of spring insteadly just for hibernate is so heavy

Answer (score 0):

If you developing a small project which have very few CRUD operations then Hibernate can avoided unless you are experience enough with Hibernate. One of the main problem is learning curve i.e. understanding ORM/Sessions etc. See following link which explains this very well:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607819/weaknesses-of-hibernate

Comment: I understand that Hibernate can be too much for some projects but I want to learn Hibernate for future reference so I believe understanding the basics on my current project will help.

Comment: Yes, definitely. If you are planning to learn for future projects then its fine. However, just a note that all java project will not use Hibernate e.g. in telecom projects where real time data/GIS data matters, use of Hibernate is disaster.

Comment: Yeah。。the database optimization work will be very hard when you use hibernate